# How to avoid unnecessary re-renders in the list? (functional component)

Tags: reactjs

I have a list that is generated in a loop. Each item on this list can be edited. After editing a list line, the list changes, but one element that has been edited, but not the rest, is changed, but all the lines of the list are rendered.
Conditions: The list is used in the function component. Each row is a component that returns JSX.
Here is my code:

```
import React, { useMemo, useCallback } from "react";
import RegionListItem from "~f/region-list-item";
import RegionListItemEdit from "~f/region-list-item-edit";
import useRegionData from "./use-region-data";

const RegionList = ({ list }) => {
  const { regions = [], changeRegion, resetRegion } = useRegionData(list);

  return (
    <ul className="list region-list">
      {regions.length &&
        regions.map(item => (
          <React.Fragment key={item._id}>
            {item.edit ? (
              <RegionListItemEdit
                item={item}
                onEdit={changeRegion}
                onReset={resetRegion}
              />
            ) : (
              <RegionListItem item={item} onEdit={changeRegion} />
            )}
          </React.Fragment>
        ))}
    </ul>
  );
};

export default RegionList;
```

Tried to use useCallback but decided nothing. And not sure if useCallback can be used in a loop:

```
import React, { useMemo, useCallback } from "react";
import RegionListItem from "~f/region-list-item";
import RegionListItemEdit from "~f/region-list-item-edit";
import useRegionData from "./use-region-data";

const RegionList = ({ list }) => {
  const { regions = [], changeRegion, resetRegion } = useRegionData(list);

  return (
    <ul className="list region-list">
      {regions.length &&
        regions.map(item => (
          <React.Fragment key={item._id}>
            {item.edit
              ? useCallback(
                  <RegionListItemEdit
                    item={item}
                    onEdit={changeRegion}
                    onReset={resetRegion}
                  />,
                  [item]
                )
              : useCallback(
                  <RegionListItem item={item} onEdit={changeRegion} />,
                  [item]
                )}
          </React.Fragment>
        ))}
    </ul>
  );
};

export default RegionList;
```

Comment: item._id is something truly unique to each item?

Comment: Yes, this is the id from the database, it is unique for each element